# Split 1 div into 2 separate div's?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible with jQuery to split 1 Div into 2 Div's at a specified point marked with tag

In this code example I was thinking would it be possible to split the div at the 'em tag' to make 
2 div's

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
    <em></em>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. get innerhtml of the div, split string on the em. then reparse it into 2 divs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to resolve your issue. For this assign an id to the parent div and remove its html after preserving its inner html. We can remove the parent div after storing its html in a variable but i dont do this because we have to place the modified html on the same place.

```
var divhtml = $("#divId").html();
var myps = divhtml.split("<em></em>");
var myhtml = "<div>"+myps[0]+"</div><div>"+myps[1]+"</div>";
$("#divId").html(myhtml);
```

If you are must to remove parent tag you can get the last element id, remove the main div after storing its html in a variable and place the modified html next after the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a main div and use append() function to append any HTML into it.
For example:

```
  <div id='main'>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  </p>

  <em></em>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  </p>

</div>
```

In JQuery:

```
varHtml = $('#main').html();

// You can use JS function to split

$('#main').html("");

$('#main').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</p><em></em>');

$('#main').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,  </p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful but will work:

```
$('div').after(function() {
    return $('<div>').append($(this).find('.break').nextAll());
}).find('.break').remove();
```

Providing that your braking element has class `.break` (`<em class="break"></em>`).

http://jsfiddle.net/U3p3e/